# Set the onclick property of a HTMLElement member in a class to a method of the same class

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to set the onclick event handler of an HTMLElement member inside of a class instance but there is a problem with both of my attempts:

## 1: keyword this can't be used

```
class ClassName {
  div: HTMLElement;
  constructor() {
    this.div = document.createElement('div');
    this.div.onclick = function(e) {
      this._onclick(); // keyword 'this' is not the instance in this scope
    }
  }
  _onclick() {
    alert('I've been clicked!');
  }
}
```

## 2: Error:'Cannot convert 'void' to (ev:FocusEvent) => any.'

```
class ClassName {
  div: HTMLElement;
  constructor() {
    this.div = document.createElement('div');
    this.div.onclick =  this._onclick(); // error
  }
  _onclick() {
    alert('I've been clicked!');
  }
}
```

I think this shows a lack of understanding of the language on my part. If someone could please clarify and possibly post a solution it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your second example probably should be ``this.div.onclick = this._onclick;`` (without the parentheses).

Comment: Damn, I've come a long way in 8 years. Thank you younger self for all the hardwork you put in, it was all worth it in the end. I miss you more than ever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use arrow notation specific to typescript:

```
class ClassName {
  div: HTMLElement;
  constructor() {
    this.div = document.createElement('div');
    this.div.onclick = (e) => {
      this._onclick(); // keyword 'this' is the instance in this scope
    }
  }
  _onclick() {
    alert('I've been clicked!');
  }
}
```

`()=>` instead of `function()` automatically escapes `this` for you e.g the following typescript:

```
class ClassName {
    foo = "123"; 
    constructor(){
        var x = ()=>{
            alert(this.foo);
        }
    }
}
```

Generates the following javascript:

```
var ClassName = (function () {
    function ClassName() {
        var _this = this;
        this.foo = "123";
        var x = function () {
            alert(_this.foo);
        };
    }
    return ClassName;
})();
```

Notice `var _this = this` which maintains `this` using closure inside the function `_this.foo`

Answer (score 4):

The `this` keyword is bound to the context in which the function is called.
When the function is called as a result of an event of a DOM element, such as `onclick`, it points to that element.

A workaround for your first example is to keep the constructor context in a new variable, which will call `that`:

```
class ClassName {
  div: HTMLElement;
  constructor() {
    this.div = document.createElement('div');
    var that = this;   //that and this both point to the new Object
    this.div.onclick = function(e) {
                       //this now points elsewhere
      that._onclick(); //that still point to the new object
    }
  }
  _onclick() {
    alert('I\'ve been clicked!');
  }
}
```

In your second example, you evaluate the `onclick` function by adding the parenthesis, so you assign its **result** to the `div.onclick` property.

A correct code is:

```
class ClassName {
  div: HTMLElement;
  constructor() {
    this.div = document.createElement('div');
    this.div.onclick =  this._onclick;
  }
  _onclick() {
    alert('I\'ve been clicked!');
  }
}
```